# Использование одного соединения контроллерами

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple

Есть приложение на *swift*, которое соединяется с сервером посредством *socket.io*.

В приложении 3 контроллера:

- стартовый (в нем осуществляется ввод данных для передачи),
- ожидание (подбор второго клента по параметрам),
- котроллер действий (тут как раз вся логика).

Собственно, проблема в том, чтобы заставить эти 3 контроллера работать от одного соединения, не разрывая его. И в зависимости от ответов сервера выводить тот или иной контроллер.

Как сделать соединение глобальным для всего приложения?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, простите, но я начинающий разработчик и не освоил полностью язык. Не совсем пониаю о чем идет речь.

Comment: ok, сейчас разверну

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним из вариантов решения будет использовать [синглтон паттерн](http://habrahabr.ru/post/198470/).

Примерно вот так:

- создать синглтон (код можно полностью скопировать из ссылки выше), который будет создаваться, например, в AppDelegate.
- в синглтон создавать socket.io соединение и после получения ответа от него заменять текущий контроллер на необходимый.

Если синглтон вам не подходит по какой-то причине, можно, чтобы текущий вью контроллер при создании следующего контроллера передавал в него информацию о socket.io соединении, например во вермя инита `[[NewController alloc] initWithSocket:self.socket]`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли. Заработало!